# Determine the indefinite integral: $I=\int \frac{\sin^5x\arcsin^5x}{e^{5x}\ln^5x}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Determine the indefinite integral:
$$
I
=
\int{\sin^{5}\left(x\right)\arcsin^{5}\left(x\right) \over {\rm e}^{5x}\ln^{5}\left(x\right)}\,{\rm d}x
$$

I have not seen this ever, so do not know how solve. Please help me come up with a method of solving the problem.

Comment: What makes you think there's a closed-form solution for problems like this?

Comment: I found this article on a math forum, but no one solution.

Comment: What article? Even if you make all the exponents $5$ equal to $1$, I expect one could prove that there is no elementary antiderivative using [differential algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)).

Comment: this article ~ this post, i don't know how, so i asked!

Comment: Is a series solution okay? Can you post a link to the forum you found it in?

Comment: Series solution seams to be the only way. Otherwise, you should use numerical methods.

Comment: I think posting a question with no definite solution has become a good way to gain reputation..

Comment: Can you integrate a gamma function? Series expansions give factorial and double factorial terms which can be represented as a gamma function.